# Issue with Safari Browser HTML CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just came across an issue. My Chrome is showing my nav like this:

[image]

But my Safari shows it like this:

[image]

Code:

```
#header{
    display: grid;
    width: 70%; margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 1%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas: 'header-left header-right';
    text-align: center;
    font-size: x-large;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: grey;
    margin-top: 2em;

}
#header-left{
    grid-area: 'header-left';
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
}

#header-right{
    grid-area: 'header-right';
}
#header-right a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: grey;
}
#about h2,p{
    text-align: left;
}
```

Can't find any fixes for this. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe try an explicit `font-size` instead of leaving it to the browser to decide what "x-large" means.

Comment: @Pointy not the issue

Comment: Have you tried it? In fact, what have you tried? What experiments have you done?

Comment: Just tried it by setting it to multiple fixed sizes.
Kinda a bad situations since it's a browser problem but I can't leave it as it may be seen by mac users aswell

Comment: it's not a browser *problem* - it's a difference. Whose to say which one is right and which is wrong - have you tried specifying a font-family and checking which font is actually used? Also, have you made sure your viewing at 100% on each browser? Browsers tend to "remember" any zoom settings per site

Comment: @JaromandaX all are at 100%, same size. Tried different font familys. Doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding `display: inline-block;` to `nav a {}`

Comment: wow ... how would that change the size of the text? Unless the images you posted aren't a true reflection of the problem (it looks like the text is bigger in Safari than it is in Chrome) ... d'oh ... oh wait - that's an artefact of embedding the images here!! It really looked like the font size was different!